# Why double/numeric value in matrix return wrong answer by using %in% a range?

Tags: r

I found integer and double values behaves differently in matrix and wrong answer returned  for double data types only.

```
#Test
m <- matrix(1:12,4,3)
which(!m[1,] %in% 1:5)

which(!m[1,] %in% 1:5)
[1] 3
```

However, when I changed the values in double/numeric,

```
m <- matrix(c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6), 4,3)
which(!m[1,] %in% 0.10:0.35)

   [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  0.1  0.5  0.3
[2,]  0.2  0.6  0.4
[3,]  0.3  0.1  0.5
[4,]  0.4  0.2  0.6

which(!m[1,] %in% 0.10:0.35)
[1] 2 3
```

only 2 should be in the answer because 1,3 are in the range of 0.10 to 0.35, why it is different in the computation using integer and numeric. Thanks!

Comment: +1 For asking a clear question with sample code, data and expected results.

Answer (score 9):

It's because you have a flawed understanding of what the `:` operator does.  `:` does not indicate a range, but is indeed a shortcut to generate sequences of discrete values (at integer intervals).

Compare:

```
> 1:5
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

> 0.1:0.35
[1] 0.1
```

So your first bit of code tests whether a value is `%in%` the range of integers 1 to 5.  But the second bit of code tests whether your data is equal to 0.1.

To get the result you are after, you need to write the following:

```
which(!(m[1, ] >= 0.1 & m[1, ] <= 0.35))
[1] 2
```

Comment: @jrara yep, I think that's what Andrie meant and I've edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @GavinSimpson.  Your editing finger is clearly much faster than mine.

Comment: It is instructive to see why `0.1:0.35` returns only `[1] 0.1`. The help for `:` explains that `from:to` is equivalent to `seq(from, to, by = 1)`, which also returns `0.1` only for the values used by the OP. This is because `(0.1 + 1) > 0.35`.